# Using matlab to fit data with negative binomial distribution under given p?

Tags: matlab

How to use matlab  to fit data with negative binomial distribution under given p?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a job for `mle` in the [statistics toolbox](http://de.mathworks.com/help/stats/index.html).  You'll need to express the negative binomial distribution (or the log of it, which will probably be easier) as a function of `p` and whatever else, and invent some starting parameters to hand in.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean fit as a function of the other parameter R with P fixed, the following shows how to use `mle` to fix the value of one parameter and estimate the other:

```
x = nbinrnd(20,.5,1000,1);
params = nbinfit(x)                                   % unconstrained fit
r = mle(x,'pdf',@(x,r)nbinpdf(x,r,.5),'start',23)     % constrain P=0.5

% Plot log likelihood as a function of R
rr = linspace(15,25);
yy = zeros(size(rr));
for j=1:length(rr)
   yy(j) = sum(log(nbinpdf(x,rr(j),.5)));
end
plot(rr,yy,'-',...
     params(1),sum(log(nbinpdf(x,params(1),params(2)))),'o')
legend(sprintf('r=%f,p=.5',r), sprintf('r=%f,p=%f',params),'location','sw')
```